# why the single linked list program is not working the way it intend to work

Tags: c

I had written a linked list program. And when I try to print the linked list its printing well. 
After that in printing function i have introduced delay (i.e. sleep(1)) so that output to be printed each node after a time period of 1 second. 
But the actual output is printing after the complete time has been elapsed (i.e. all nodes are printing after a time period of 10 second). Can you please explain what is the reason behind this unexpected behaviour in output.

void print_list(const Node *local_head)
{
    for(const Node *current = local_head; current != NULL; current = current->next) {
        printf("%d -> ", current->value);
        sleep(1);
    }
    printf("\n");
    printf("**** End of List ****\n");
}

int main()
{
    int i;
    Node *head = create_node(10);
    head = append_node(head, create_node(10));
    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        head = append_node(head, create_node(20));
        head = prepend_node(head, create_node(30));
    }

    print_list(head);

    return 0;
}

Comment: @user3121023 Please make an answer.

Comment: @user3121023, Thanks for your reply and after adding fflush its working properly. I am bit confused with printf working in these scenarios and where my understanding is going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Output to `stdout` (which is the `FILE *` that `printf` writes to) is *buffered*. More specifically line-buffered (when connected to a terminal).

That means the output won't actually be written to the terminal unless the buffer is flushed, which happens on four conditions: The `FILE *` is closed, the buffer is full, there is a newline, or you explicitly flush it with the [`fflush`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fflush) function.

For your use-case the best solution would be to call `fflush` in the loop before sleeping:

```
for(const Node *current = local_head; current != NULL; current = current->next) {
    printf("%d -> ", current->value);
    fflush(stdout);  // Make sure the buffer is flushed and written to the terminal
    sleep(1);
}
```

Comment: As per your explanation tried with new line character [printf("%d -> \n", current->value);] and its working.